# Why does setting the Navigation bar color crash Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I added the code below to `NavigationController.m`, but when I try to run the app in the simulator it crashes Xcode. What is wrong with this code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureRecognized:)]];

    if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
        // iOS 6.1 or earlier
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        // iOS 7.0 or later
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    }

}
```

Comment: Which simulator ? 6.1 or greater ?

Comment: Can you provide a little bit of context on your crash ? 
Did you implement the callback for your gesture recognizer ?

Comment: He was asking what simulator version not iOS.

Comment: Provide the crash log, please.

Comment: There is no crash log. Xcode completely crashes together with the simulator. But yes, 6.1

Comment: you still should have something in your console that describes the origin of the crash.

Comment: comment line `self.view addGestureRecognizer` and let me know if still crash occurs... I think crash reason is bcz method `panGestureRecognized ` is not defined...

Comment: If you have code that actually crashes Xcode and the simulator then you should file a bug report with Apple. Include the app project and instructions to reproduce the Xcode crash.